# Applications of systems with multiple time

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, examples, applications

A dynamical system with multiple time is an action of a group $\mathbb{Z}^d$ or $\mathbb{R}^d$ on a metric space.

I am interested in informative examples and applications of such systems. I know about subshifts and thermodynamic formalism, but I hope there
are also examples which are used in control theory.